# Permisos en tiempo de ejecuccion

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente código

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            }
        }
```

en cual pregunta si se tiene permisos para acceder a los contactos y para leer la memoria , esta aca todo bien , el problema viene a la hora de rechazar el permiso.

Si lo rechazo y vuelvo para otra activdad , al volver a esta debería volver a preguntar si acepto o no el permiso pero no lo hace ,

> ¿no se supone que esto verifica si tiene permiso y si no lo tiene lo
>   pide de nuevo ?

Comment: Tu código es "correcto", elimina el uso de shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale, en mi respuesta explico la razón. De esta forma puedes siempre mostrar el diálogo para requerir permisos si es que no los has aceptado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruno, en realidad el código que muestras, revisa si tienes definido el permiso, en caso de no ser así, muestra el dialogo para requerirlos.

Estas son las definiciones de los métodos que usas:

> **shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()**: Este método muestra true si la app solicita el permiso anteriormente y el usuario rechaza la solicitud.
>   **Nota:** Si el usuario rechaza la solicitud de permiso en el pasado y selecciona la opción Don't ask again en el diálogo de solicitud de permiso del sistema, el método muestra false. También muestra false si una política de dispositivo prohíbe que la app tenga ese permiso
>
> **requestPermissions()** Para mostrar el dialogo de petición.
>
> **checkSelfPermission()** Para revisar el permiso.

en realidad el método que usas no lo vuelve a requerir, debes prescindir de `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` ya que si rechazas la solicitud el dialogo no se vuelve a mostrar.

Para volver a requerirlos simplemente revisa si los tienes, si no es así, llama el método `requestPermissions()`:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //* Si no estan asignados los permisos, vuelve a mostrar el dialogo para requerirlos.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

}
```

Esto lograría que cada vez que llames el tu código para requerir permisos, si no lo tiene se mostraría el diálogo.

Comment: muchas gracias Jorge , la verdad como siempre tus respuestas muy completas  y dedicadas , !

Comment: Hola Bruno, que bueno resolviste el problema, un saludos!

Comment: Mas que resolverlo yo ,  me lo resolviste vos ! ,

Answer (score 3):

Te respondo por este medio porque todavía no puedo comentar, en fin.

Lo que tendrías que hacer es sobreescribir el método `onRequestPermissionsResult()` y ahí controlas su respuesta. Con esto me refiero a que si el usuario intenta rechazar el permiso tu le ***muestres un mensaje o diálogo*** diciéndole que es necesario o crucial para la app que él acepte dichos permisos.

No se que tan importante sean para ti, yo tuve un problema similar donde prácticamente forzaba al usuario a aceptar mis permisos de Ubicación, si el usuario aceptaba iba todo bien, si lo rechazaba le mostraba un mensaje mencionando su importancia, y si volvía a rechazarlo, hago que acepte los permisos manualmente desde los 'Ajustes' de Android.

Te dejo un [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719047/android-m-check-runtime-permission-how-to-determine-if-the-user-checked-nev) de referencia que me guió un poco en el camino. Cualquier consulta puedes preguntar. Saludos!

Comment: gracias MegaHerx , lo que me parece raro que una vez rechazado , no pueda yo volver a mostrarle el cartel para que acepte o no , solo si desintalo la aplicacion pero parece que ser asi