# Solicitud de Permisos

Tags: java, android

Actualmente me encuentro pidiendo permisos de manera separada:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // no explico el porque es importante aceptar
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        }



if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
                // no explico porque es importante aceptar el permiso
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            }
        }
```

Se me hace imposible unir esto todo en un solo método , no entiendo la sintaxis ,¿Alguien podría echarme una mano ?, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes verificar primeramente si ambos permisos estan aceptados mediante el operador &&, si alguno no se tiene, se requiere, en este caso puedes agregar los permisos en el array:

```
new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}
```

Código:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No tiene permisos" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "tiene Permisos" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Te recomiendo usar  `requestPermissions`, en lugar de `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge!

Comment: Un placer, recuerda usar requestPermissions y NO shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale por el problema que ocurrió aquí  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115475/permisos-en-tiempo-de-ejecuccion saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Intenta pedir por multiples permisos especificandolo en el array de string los permisos que estas solicitando:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
    new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
    },
    PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Einer!