# ¿Debug-Log a distancia? Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy desarrollando una app la cual tiene inconvenientes con dos versiones de android, ya se ha instalado en diferentes android, 4.4.4, 5, 6. pero hay dos smartphone que se les detiene la app uno es la versión 6.0.1 y el otro android 8 oreo. No se a que puede ser la falla pues pruebo la app en mis emuladores y todo va de maravilla.

> ¿Existe un método para poder ver el log o debug de la app a un android
>   que este en otro lugar del mundo?

Y así poder ver que es lo que provoca la falla.

Comment: Puedes implementar crashlitycs, forma parte de Firebase https://firebase.google.com/?hl=es-419 y en 30 minutos lo tienes funcionando.

Comment: Mi app no estará/esta en la app store, aún puedo usar de esta herramienta? Asi sea que no cuente con lo de google play?

Comment: @DamiánGonzálezFernández He integrado el firebase, sin embargo aun no me queda claro lo de integrar "FirebaseCrash.log("Activity created");" eso lo tengo que agregar en todos los activitys? o solo en el activity principal.

Comment: @LuisRivas tu aplicación esta publicada en la Google playstore? Porque no agregas que realiza tu aplicación, un poco de codigo, de hecho si agregas que permisos tienen en el androidmanifest.xml? esto puede indicar el problema ya que comentas se detiene en determinados os. Revisa también : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110391/qu%C3%A9-es-crashlytics-de-fabric-y-c%C3%B3mo-configurarlo-para-android

Comment: @Jorgesys la aplicación se ha instalado al rededor de 52 dispositivos, los cuales solo 2 ha fallado, me coloque en contacto con esos usuarios y me di cuenta que al instalar al app el tema que estos tenian no iba con el tema de la aplicación (me refiero a la interfaz, ejemplo digamos que el fondo del login activity es negro, y tiene imagenes, el ic_launcher es una flecha, bueno al ver los captures de estos, salio la interfaz en blanco y el ic_launcher que trae por defecto android_studio. Quede WTF. -La aplicacion no esta en la play store.

Comment: @LuisRivas agrega tu AndroidManifest.xml para una respuesta precisa. Lo del tema puede no ser problema para cerrar la aplicación, los permisos si!

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/ :)

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/application-insights-adds-support-for-ios-and-android-apps-improved-java-app-support-and-fine-time-selection/

Comment: @fredyfx maestro FredyFx agregué la recomendación a mi respuesta.

Comment: gracias maestro @Jorgesys :D es un honor formar parte de vuestra respuesta, muy acertada por cierto :D

Comment: @LuisRivas sobre lo que comentabas antes, no necesitas hacer FirebaseCrash.log para nada, con hacer la integración básica Crashlitycs ya va a recoger todos los cuelgues de tu App y enviarte el log, eso que pones solo lo necesitarías usar en caso de que quieras loguear tu una parte concreta de tu aplicación, pero como te digo, con la librería configurada de forma básica ya vas a tener suficiente.

Comment: Sí. Muchas veces estoy debugeando (y la versión aún no está subida a la store) y me saltan los errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para generar un registro de eventos que ocurren en tu aplicación y que estan ocasionando problemas como lo son ANR o Crashes, puedes revisar:

[**Google Play Console.**](https://developer.android.com/distribute/console/)

En el caso de tener tu aplicación publicada en Google Play Store, en la consola de administración puedes dar seguimiento a problemas que están ocurriendo en tu aplicación, ya sean ANR (Android no responde) o Crashes (Errores), entra a [**Android Vitals**](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/) y posteriormente **[ANR´s](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr)** o **[Crashes](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/crash)**,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes visualizar el listado y acceder a información más detallada del error, incluso puedes visualizar el stacktrace.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[**Fabric - Crashlytics**](https://get.fabric.io/)

Este framework puede ser implementado de una manera sencilla en tu aplicación y puedes obtener información acerca de errores en tu aplicación pero a diferencia de Google Play Console, no necesitas tener publicada tu aplicación, el registro de errores se realizara si la aplicación cuenta con conexión a internet.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes revisar más información aquí:

[¿Qué es Crashlytics de Fabric y cómo configurarlo para Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110391/qu%C3%A9-es-crashlytics-de-fabric-y-c%C3%B3mo-configurarlo-para-android)

[**Application Insights**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/)

Recomendada por nuestro amigo @FredyFx

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/application-insights-adds-support-for-ios-and-android-apps-improved-java-app-support-and-fine-time-selection/

---

Con respecto a el error que muestra tu aplicación :

> se ha instalado en diferentes android, 4.4.4, 5, 6. pero hay dos
>   smartphone que se les detiene la app uno es la versión 6.0.1 y el otro
>   android 8 oreo.

Debes recordar que para los sistemas operativos a partir de Android 6.0 (API 23) algunos [permisos que son considerados riesgosos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions?hl=es#auto-adjustments):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

deben ser requeridos en tiempo de ejecución y no es suficiente con agregarlos dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Revisa la documentación : [Cómo solicitar permisos durante el tiempo de ejecución](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es)

Ejemplos:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)

[Permisos en tiempo de ejecuccion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115475/permisos-en-tiempo-de-ejecuccion/115490#115490)

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración de los permisos, ya tenía definido el permiso de READ/WRITE y si no estaba aceptado mandaba la solicitud del permiso, pero aun me faltaba el de READ_PHONE_STATE que no sabía que estaba como riesgoso D: , Ya agrege firebase+fabric y esta de maravilla. Ya lo había visto anteriormente, pero pensé que se requería que estuviera la app en google play.

Comment: En realidad he visto varios reportes de aplicaciones que marcan error pero es porque se requiere pedir permisos manualmente, esto no sería necesario si tu targetsdk fuera menor de 23 pero obviamente requerimos actualizarlos. En el caso de Fabric no es necesario, creo que es un plus.

Answer (score 1):

Como comentaba Damián, yo en mi trabajo uso Fabric que tiene integración con Firebase. Te dan gran cantidad de datos (tipo de dispositivo, versión, etc) al igual que te da el log del error junto con la memoria utilizada. También tienes datos a tiempo real como por ejemplo la cantidad de usuarios que están usando la app en ese momento. No sólo eso, si no que también puedes crear eventos personalizados para saber cosas en ciertos puntos de la aplicación. Echale un ojo que sin duda te va a ayudar.

https://get.fabric.io/

Comment: Mi app no estará/esta en la app store, aún puedo usar de esta herramienta? Asi sea que no cuente con lo de google play?

Comment: Sí. Muchas veces estoy debugeando (y la versión aún no está subida a la store) y me saltan los errores.

Answer (score 1):

Si al producirse el fallo, el usuario usa el diálogo de Enviar Reporte (no me acuerdo el nombre exacto), se enviará un reporte que puedes revisar en la Consola de Play, bajo el título "Android vitals > Errores ANR y bloqueos."

Sobre esta Consola mira: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6083203?hl=es

Si mal no recuerdo, creo que se podía ver el stacktrace, que muchas veces alcanza para identificar por dónde viene el problema.

Comment: En los últimos OS ya no se necesita que el usuario envié el reporte, afortunadamente.